# How to add a redirect after vagrant ssh

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am new to Vagrant. I have tested different boxes for different cms. Like [Drupal VM](https://www.drupalvm.com/) and [VCCW](http://vccw.cc/).

In the first scenario, with DruaplVM, after entering into the virtual machine with `vagrant ssh` it sends me to the actual Drupal site. Directly.

I want to do the same for the VCCW, after entering, I want to go to Vagrant/Wordpress, but I don't really know how that works in Vagrant. I am checking the code in the DrupalVM project, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: I don't understand. After `vagrant ssh` you can just do `cd /vagrant/wordpress`. Do you want to avoid issuing the `cd` command ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is just linux `.bashrc` routine.

You can use the following `Vagrantfile` as an example to achieve your goal:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "vccw-team/xenial64"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    echo "cd /vagrant/wordpress" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
    . /home/vagrant/.bashrc 
  SHELL
end
```

And after `vagrant up` we have:

```
$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-87-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

2 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/wordpress$ pwd
/vagrant/wordpress
```